# Run Laravel as a script in the Background on already existing website

Tags: php, laravel

I have this simple PHP script right now which saves some data about the visitor (IP, location, user agent, time of visit, URL, etc) in the database. This script lies in the footer of all my pages on the website as an external file using:

`<?php  include('simple_analitics.php') ?>`

Now I have some basic knowledge about the Laravel framework and how it works.

I want to move all of this `simple_analitics.php` script into a nice and simple Laravel application and then develop it a bit more. My question is the following:

How can I include this Laravel aplication in my existing website so that wherever the visitor comes on the website, the laravel aplication kicks in in the background and does it's thing? I must mention that this aplication will not return anything to the View, it would only collect some data, do some logic and then save it to the database. I just don't know how to include it in my existing website.

I would be very grateful for a some suggestions or at least a little guidance, because to be honest i don't even know where to start.

Comment: Ajax is where you start...

Comment: It this file is not displying anything, you can put include statement inside `app/start/global.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to expose the existence of this other app (because using Ajax would let someone see the call using Developer Tools, and potentially make separate additional calls to it and mess with your analytics), then from your existing application you could use something like:

```php
$null = file_get_contents("http://your-laravel-app.com");
```

This will make a web request to the URL behind-the-scenes on your server (and not from the client - so if you're tracking client IP and other such details you would have to pass those in your call, something like:

```
$null = file_get_contents("http://your-laravel-app.com?IP={$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");
```

And so on..

If you include this in your footer the same way you were including the other stuff, it should just work, without creating any dependencies between the two.